# Javascript Button onclick change

Tags: javascript

I need to make a button that when clicking on execute a function and then after change As if it was a button on / off, that performs 2 functions 1 in each button used with css and only with pure javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
<p id="red"> Paragrafo 01</p>




<input type="button" 
 value= "cor" onclick="mudarred();" />

 <script>
    function mudarred(){
  if()
        document.getElementById('red').style.color="red";
    else
    document.getElementById('red').style.color="blue";

    }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/wkLgd7nf/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I modified your jsfidle [check this](https://jsfiddle.net/waeu39tr/)

```
let firstCall = true;
function mudarred(){
    if(firstCall){
        document.getElementById('red').style.color="red";
        firstCall= false;
    }else{
        firstCall=true;
        document.getElementById('red').style.color="blue";
    }
}
```

Comment: How could I do to increase and decrease a text with this same code?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "only with pure JS", but [`classList.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) is great for this. I would also recommend that you keep your styles in CSS, not JS or HTML.

```js
const buttonElement = document.querySelector('.js-toggle-button')
const paragraphElement = document.querySelector('.js-paragraph')

buttonElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
  paragraphElement.classList.toggle('paragraph--off')
})
```

```css
.paragraph {
  color: red;
}

/* Overrides because of specificity */
.paragraph--off {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p class="js-paragraph paragraph">Paragraph</p>
<button class="js-toggle-button">Toggle</button>
```